# Error while filtering pivot table in EXCEL (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a pivot table in which im trying to apply a filter with the following code:

```
Dim Brand_CodePF As pivotField
      Set Brand_CodePF = BrandSellingSTItem_SalesWS.PivotTables("Brand SellingState Item Pivot sales").PivotFields("BrandCode")

      With Brand_CodePF
      .ClearAllFilters
        .CurrentPage = dataBrand
        End With

     Dim Selling_StatePF As pivotField
     Set Selling_StatePF = BrandSellingSTItem_SalesWS.PivotTables("Brand SellingState Item Pivot sales").PivotFields("SellingSTCode")

        With Selling_StatePF
      .ClearAllFilters

        **.CurrentPage = GLSellingState_**
        On Error Resume Next
        End With
```

The line i have highligted with with * * is giving me an error. I have checked my data , it seems the value upon which i want to filter doesn't exist in that pivot that is, GLSellingState is not in that pivot, however i want to handle such a case , i want my application to simply move on to the next iteration of my code ( I have all this inside my loop) how do i achieve this?

Comment: There remains lot of guess work for any one to attempt answering your question. If you provide few lines of sanitized source data, current pivot structure and the code or process which you adopted so far .ie. created pivot table with wizard following VBA code or by native facilities of Excel etc. All such details help in getting proper answer. Majority of Pivot Table questions remains half answered here on SO. For example Field.CurrentPage only works for Filter fields (also called page fields). 
If you want to filter a row/column field, you have to cycle through the individual items decisions

Comment: I think what im asking is fairly simple, i dont have the data in my SellingState field (Page field ) as you mentioned on which i want to filter, however this throws an excel  in vba when i try to filter it for that data through the above code. How can i handle this case? Ie, if the data is not being available for filtering, i want to go to the next iteration of my loop in which this process is being done.

Comment: General routine is as follows. I do not prefer submitting answers without full data and reasonable verification. `Sub FilterPivotField(Field As PivotField, Value)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Field
        If .Orientation = xlPageField Then
            .CurrentPage = Value
        ElseIf .Orientation = xlRowField Or .Orientation = xlColumnField Then
            Dim i As Long
            On Error Resume Next ' Needed to avoid getting errors when manipulating PivotItems that were deleted from the data source.` ..contd.

Comment: `' Set first item to Visible to avoid getting no visible items while working
            .PivotItems(1).Visible = True
            For i = 2 To Field.PivotItems.Count
                If .PivotItems(i).Name = Value Then _
                    .PivotItems(i).Visible = True Else _
                    .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
            Next i
            If .PivotItems(1).Name = Value Then _
                .PivotItems(1).Visible = True Else _
                .PivotItems(1).Visible = False
        End If
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub`

Comment: @skkakkar why not write your code as answer ? where it easier to the eyes, and you can add some comments. I have a similar code before, it's the better aproach (for me atleast)

Comment: @Shai Rado At least in Pivot tables I am careful. I have seen that generic types of questions lend into problems when OP tests  the code and spell out requirements which are quite different at times.If you like you can submit the answer, I have no problem in it.